# One over 2 times itself?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question asks to simplify the following:

$\pi + 2/(\pi+ 2/(\pi + 2/(   ...$  repeats

Having difficulty seeing the reduction of this.  Any ideas?  The answer to the question seems to indicate that it does reduce/simplify.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant

$$x:=\pi+\frac2{\pi+\frac2{\pi+\ldots}}=\pi+\frac2x\implies x^2-\pi x-2=0$$

Now just solve the above quadratic equation.

Note that the above assumes you can *prove* the continuos fraction converges. The rest is just algebra and arithmetic of limits.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

$y = \pi + \dfrac{2}{\pi + \dfrac{2}{\pi + \cdots}}$ Obviously this expression is greater than $\pi$, thus greater than $0$.

$y = \pi + \dfrac{2}{y}$ because denominator is $y$ itself.

$y^2 = \pi y + 2$  because $y \neq 0$

$y^2 - \pi y -2 = 0$

Now you can solve this quadratic and eliminate the root which is greater than $\pi$ as argued earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I see now how this is the solution to the problem, but what if it just says to simplify?

Comment: I suppose $y = \pi + \dfrac{2}{y}$ is a lot more simpler than the original complicated looking form, isn't it?

Comment: I guess so.  I always thought that since the expression was given without an equals sign then to simplify I needed to keep the expression as an expression and not turn it into an equation.

Comment: It is true in most of the cases, but here it's impossible to simplify in expression state.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\pi+\cfrac{2}{\pi+\cfrac{2}{\pi+\cfrac{2}{\pi+\dots}}}$.

Then $x-\pi=\frac{2}{x}$.

So $x^2-\pi x-2=0$.

Comment: I very much appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I can see this is the SOLUTION, but the problem didn't say solve, it said simplify.

Comment: I would say that if we applied the quadratic formula to get a value for $x$, the form would be simpler than the given (continued fraction) form.